# Swift playgrounds on iPad, NSLog does not show any messages on "Console.app" on macOS

Tags: swift, ipad, swift-playground

Console.app shows "private message" when I call NSLog on Swift playgrounds.
Should I do anything in order to use NSLog?

I use Swift playgrounds 2.1 on iPad Pro(iOS12 beta10).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift Playgrounds on iPad, there really isn't a need to use `NSLog`. Could you please specify if there is a specific reason? You should be fine with `print()`. Even if you don't `print()`, then it shows in the result box next to it anyway. Hope this helped.